# Automatically scaling numbers in a table using stargazer

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I wish to create a number of tables with numerical elements of very different scales. For example, tables with the variance of various variables down the diagonal, and the correlations off the diagonal. The larger numbers make the tables too big, and are harder to read.

Is there a good way using stargazer (or some other, similar package) to scale down the elements that are much larger, and indicate this with a foot note, or automatically use exponential notation?

For example, the following r code creates a matrix where the diagonal elements are much larger than the other elements.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(25,0,1),5,5)
diag(x) <- rnorm(5,10000000,10)
stargazer(x,summary=F,digits=2)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do some adaptation of this:

```
ifelse(x < 100, sprintf("%0.2f", x), sprintf("%0.5e", x))
#    [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]         
#[1,] "9.99999e+06" "-0.79"       "-0.56"       "0.91"        "-2.57"      
#[2,] "-0.13"       "9.99999e+06" "-1.83"       "-0.34"       "1.73"       
#[3,] "-0.48"       "0.38"        "1.00000e+07" "1.40"        "-0.32"      
#[4,] "-0.05"       "-0.62"       "0.91"        "1.00000e+07" "1.15"       
#[5,] "-0.09"       "-0.33"       "-0.16"       "0.35"        "9.99999e+06"
```

Or, without quotes:

```
noquote(ifelse(x < 100, sprintf("%0.2f", x), sprintf("%0.5e", x)))
#     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       
#[1,] 9.99999e+06 -0.79       -0.56       0.91        -2.57      
#[2,] -0.13       9.99999e+06 -1.83       -0.34       1.73       
#[3,] -0.48       0.38        1.00000e+07 1.40        -0.32      
#[4,] -0.05       -0.62       0.91        1.00000e+07 1.15       
#[5,] -0.09       -0.33       -0.16       0.35        9.99999e+06
```

You are essentially converting to text for printing in your desired way. For more info on output options, see `?sprintf`.